# Teclado virtual Android Firemonkey repetindo palavras

Tags: android, firemonkey, teclado, delphi-10

Temos um aplicativo Android que está apresentando problemas na digitação após enviar uma mensagem.
O problema acontece quando tentamos inserir uma nova mensagem, após digitar o primeiro caractere, o TMemo insere automaticamente todo o conteúdo da mensagem anterior.

Estamos utilizando o Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, já tentamos alterar `KeyboardType = Alphabet` e `FTextView.setIsPassword(True)`, mas não obtivemos sucesso, alguém já passou por esse problema?

Obs: não ocorre em todos os aparelhos/teclados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso ainda não tenha resolvido o problema, pode tentar conforme sugestão do Jefferson Rudolf:

Edite a unit FMX.Platform.Android.pas, alterando as duas ocorrências
de FTextView.setIsPassword(Password) para FTextView.setIsPassword(True).

No meu caso, copiei a unit para a pasta do meu projeto e fiz as alterações nessa cópia e adicionei ao projeto para garantir o uso dela, sem alterar a unit original.

Resolveu em todos os aparelhos que testamos (LG, Samsung, Asus e Alcatel).

Att,

David